# Finding last row when data skips a blank and not include data after blank

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that finds the last row of data in a column and selects all the data. My data has a break a third of the way down where an empty row is placed. I want to be able to find the last row of data before the break and not include the data that is in the same column after the break. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

```
Sub Resort()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Workbench Report")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

ws.Select
ws.Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Select

ws.Columns("B:G").Sort key1:=ws.Range("E1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns

ws.Select
ws.Range("E2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have so far?

Comment: Yes sorry I have added the code and I am trying to sort the column so thats what the rest is. Thanks!

Comment: Probably: `lastrow = ws.Cells(2, "E").End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: try this: lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.End` function on the cell. This should select the range you want.

```
Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(Cells(2, "E").End(xlDown).row, "G")).Select
```

I assume you are looking to sort only the rows above the break, so the following should do the trick.

```
Sub Resort()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Workbench Report")

ws.Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(Cells(2, "E").End(xlDown).row, "G")).Select
Selection.Sort key1:=ws.Range("E1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns

End Sub
```

Granted you could also make this a one liner

```
Sub Resort()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Workbench Report")

ws.Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(Cells(2, "E").End(xlDown).row, "G")).Sort _
    key1:=ws.Range("E1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lastrow = lastRowOfRange(range("b2").currentregion)

Function lastRowOfRange(rng As Range)
    Dim adr
    adr = Split(rng.Address, "$")
    lastRowOfRange = adr(UBound(adr))
End Function
```

---

You could also use

```
lastrow = rngLastCell(range("b2").CurrentRegion).row 

Function rngLastCell(rng As Range) As Range
'returns the last cell of a range
    Set rngLastCell = rng.Cells(0, 0).Offset(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
End Function
```